# DATEDIFF function in hibernate criteria query

Tags: jpa, hibernate-criteria, datediff, criteria-api

I have to convert the below query into hibernate criteria query:

```
select * from tbl1 t1,tbl2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id 
and ( To_char(t1.modified_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - To_char(get_sys_date, 'YYYYMMDD') )>10;
```

where get_sys_date is a sql function.

When I use datediff function in my java code like:

```
 Expression<String> day = cb.literal("day");
 Expression<Integer> diff = cb.function("DATEDIFF", Integer.class, day, currentDate, 
 root.get(myVO_.modified_date));
```

it gives me a compile error:

```
method function in interface CriteriaBuilder cannot be applied to given types
```

'currentDate' is passed as a param to the method.

How to write the creteria expression then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

By using `ParameterExpression<Date> param   =   cb.parameter(Date.class);`

we can achieve this.
And then :

```
TypedQuery<myVO> tq = this.entityManager.createQuery(cq);
tq.setParameter(param, currentDate);
return tq.getResultList();
```